# Is the Wall-Follower Algorithm in P?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Is the [wall-follower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) algorithm a poly-time algorithm (for Perfect Mazes)?

In particular, are there poly time algorithms for solving the Perfect Maze problems?

A perfect maze has the following properties:

- no inaccessible areas and is simply connected.
- no closed loops
- one and only one path from any point to any other point.
- the maze has exactly one solution.

Comment: strangely phrased.  wouldn't it make more sense to reverse the first two sentences?  "Are there poly time algorithms for solving the Perfect Maze problems?  In particular, is the wall-follower algorithm a poly-time algorithm (for Perfect Mazes)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a polynomial-time algorithm for solving perfect mazes: depth-first search solves them, and runs in polynomial time.  Actually, depth-first search is more general, as it can handle loops and other structures, too.

Breadth-first search also works, and will give you the fastest way out of the maze, but is only implementable on a computer given the full description of the maze.  In contrast, depth-first search can be implemented by a human with a piece of chalk and a ball of string -- the piece of chalk allows you to mark rooms as visited, and the ball of string lets you simulate the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Wall-following is exactly depth-first search with a specific order on the children of each vertex. So, as D.W. points out, it's a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Note that, unlike other kinds of depth search first, it doesn't use any memory.  So it's not just a particular case of DFS, there's something fundamentally different about the algorithm.

Comment: @DonHatch No, it's just what's often called depth-first tree search.  (Tree search is searching where you assume that the graph is a tree, so you don't bother remembering where you've been because it's "impossible" to get into a cycle.)

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's true, assuming  node has a pointer to its first child, child knows its next sibling, and the last child has a pointer back to the parent.    Isn't it strange to call that data structure a tree though? It seems like some transform of a tree.   Usually when people talk about DFS (e.g. wikipedia) it's only the parent storing pointers to its children (or at least that's all the algorithm looks at), and a runtime stack used to remember how to unwind.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly natural representation of a tree, to me. If you want to store a tree where vertices don't have a fixed number of children, you're going to have to use a linked list of some kind and you may as well do that by giving each vertex a "next sibling" pointer. And giving every vertex a pointer back to its parent also seems natural (even though the algorithm here only uses that pointer for the last child).